# Using Roboform with PuTTY

Tags: ssh, password-management, roboform

I recently discovered and fell in love with Roboform. In less than a week it's become indispensable.

So far I've only seen Roboform's ability to fill out fields in web browsers and Windows GUI apps. I'm an app developer and sometimes I need to use Telnet/SSH. My SSH client of choice is PuTTY, but I can't find any way to integrate Roboform with PuTTY. Is this possible? If not, is there another [free] SSH client that will work with Roboform?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're hoping to accomplish? Would it be roboform entering passwords when you initiate an ssh connection? Something else?

Comment: Yes; once the terminal window opens, I am prompted for a login and password. Is there a way for Roboform to input them into a terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> once the terminal window opens, I am prompted for a login...

Save the username in PuTTY settings, *Connection → Data → Login details*.

> ...and password. Is there a way for Roboform to input them into a terminal?

Do not use Roboform for that.

The recommended way for automatic SSH logins is to set up *public-key authentication*.

1. Create a keypair using PuTTYgen.

   - Save the private key using *Actions → Save private key*.
2. Tell your SSH server to allow logins using that keypair.

   1. In PuTTYgen, select all text in the *"Public key for pasting ..."* box, and copy it to clipboard.
   2. Log in to your server. Open the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in a text editor.
   3. Paste the public key into a line of its own, and save the file.

      - Make sure the key does not get word-wrapped. If you use `pico`/`nano`, run it with the `-w` option.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried your method and it works. I was just hoping for a solution that included the automation power of my new toy, since I work from four different workstations.

Comment: @Jake: So copy the key to the other workstations. Also add it to StartUp so that it will be loaded to Pageant automatically.